# Implicit ordering of case classes scala

Tags: scala, implicit, case-class, shapeless

Case classes do not seem to have an implicit ordering in scala.

```
scala> case class A(i:Int)
defined class A

scala> implicitly[Ordering[A]]
<console>:10: error: No implicit Ordering defined for A.
              implicitly[Ordering[A]]
```

I want to know if there is anyway to generically define an implicit ordering for all case classes, if not is there at least a way to define implicit ordering for each arity of case classes / case classes of the same member types.

Comment: Why would you want that? Consider that, even in the case of limiting it by arity, you have no idea what type the first element is, so you would have to find some way of comparing an arbitrary object with another arbitrary object

Comment: @MarioCamou well with implicits you can override anyway, this is just something I want for a bunch of 1-time use case classes

Comment: Last year I wrote [a blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/10/13/ordering-case-classes/) about exactly this question. It's worth noting, though, that the non-generic solution (`implicit def OrderingA: Ordering[A] = Ordering.by(_.i)`) isn't that bad at all.

Comment: @TravisBrown just looking for an easy way make all case classes ordered, you could post an answer as well if you have a method that doesn't involve using an external lib

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Orderings for case classes can be automatically derived using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless),

```
import GenericOrdering._

case class Foo(i : Int, s : String)

implicitly[Ordering[Foo]]
val fs = List(
  Foo(2, "b"),
  Foo(2, "a"),
  Foo(1, "c")
).sorted
assert(fs == List(
  Foo(1, "c"),
  Foo(2, "a"),
  Foo(2, "b")
))
```

See [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/ordering.scala) for the complete example. The full mechanics and an extension to `PartialOrdering` will be part of the forthcoming shapeless 2.1.0 release.

Comment: When in doubt, use shapeless.

Comment: I'm not complaining but technically you're supposed to explicitly state when the link you are giving is a promotion of your own product. Anyway this framework seems cool, would it allow variadic style templates like in c++11

Comment: What? No `ProductTypeClass`? :)

Comment: @aaronman I've never seen those disclosure strictures being applied to FOSS projects ... in any case it's pretty obvious that I'm one of it's authors. In answer to your question wrt ariadic style templates ... yes.

Comment: @TravisBrown Hmm ... you have a point. However, we've just acquired primitive `Ordering`/`PartialOrdering` instances for `HList` and `Coproduct` and for whatever reason it didn't occur to me to ask that question.

Comment: @MilesSabin awesome I've always felt that the lack of that feature is somewhat limiting in writing truly generic code

Comment: @MilesSabin my scala is not super strong, would it be possible to write something like [`zip`](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools#zip) (my code ;) ) in scala for an arbitrary number of args with different types?

Comment: @MilesSabin sorry for asking it here but can you point to some wiki/tutorial/blog that is a *good* source for learning shapeless?

Comment: @aaronman [it is](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/hlist.scala#L1352). Note that zip == unzip == transpose.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness I'll be the bad angel to Miles's good solution. You can in fact roll your own version of this functionality pretty easily with a macro:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

object OrderingHelper {
  implicit def apply[A]: Ordering[A] = macro apply_impl[A]

  def apply_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._

    val A = weakTypeOf[A]

    val fields = A.decls.collect {
      case sym: MethodSymbol if sym.isCaseAccessor => q"a.${sym.name}"
    }

    if (fields.isEmpty) c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not a case class!") else
      A.baseClasses.collectFirst {
        case sym
          if sym.name.decodedName.toString.startsWith("Tuple")
          && sym.owner == typeOf[Any].typeSymbol.owner =>
            c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not needed for tuples!")
      } getOrElse c.Expr[Ordering[A]](q"Ordering.by((a: $A) => (..$fields))")
  }
}
```

And then:

```
scala> import OrderingHelper._
import OrderingHelper._

scala> case class B(i: Int, s: String)
defined class B

scala> Ordering[B]
res0: scala.math.Ordering[B] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@2c9df057

scala> Ordering[B].compare(B(1, "foo"), B(1, "bar"))
res1: Int = 1
```

The code above will work in the REPL with no extra dependencies in 2.11, and for 2.10 you just need some small adjustments and a compiler plugin (see [my blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/10/13/ordering-case-classes/) for details).

I'd definitely recommend the Shapeless approach, though—Shapeless gives you a much more usefully constrained toolkit for this kind of generic programming.

Comment: When I first looked at macros they seemed somewhat useless, the quasiquotes (however dangerous they look) seem like you could actually get something done

Comment: Yeah, quasiquotes are a huge improvement over building ASTs by hand, and they're no more dangerous (although I agree that the whole idea of code in strings is kind of squicky at first).